# Shortened Drush option

Tags: drush

I am trying to write a shortened Drush option - we want to have an option for both `--force` as well as `-f`

I'm searching everywhere and not seeing any documentation, but it seems like something like it is supported based on this page:

```
https://groups.drupal.org/drush/commands
```

What I've got so far:

```
function parsexml_drush_command() {

  $items['parsexml'] = array(
    'description' => 'Parses XML from an XML feed.',
    'aliases' => array('pxml'),
    'arguments' => array(
      'path' => 'Path to the XML file.',
    ),
    'options' => array(
      'force' => 'Flag to force processing of previously processed XML files.',
      'f' => 'Shortened flag to force processing of previously processed XML files.',
    ),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

But my guess is that that isn't correct.

What is the correct way to have multiple aliases per option? I can only find how to set the alias for a given drush command.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, [Drush reserves all short (-f) options for use exclusively by Drush core](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/includes/command.inc#L748).  You cannot define them in contrib extensions.

See the function [drush_get_global_options](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/includes/drush.inc#L267) for an example of how to define options that have attributes; the short option is 'short-form', although this does not work right for non-Core commands.